# Intersect two intervals

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there a way I can test if an interval given by two attributes within a table intersetcs another one which is "hard-coded"? Let´s say we have a table

```
a | b
2 | 3
4 | 6
1 | 2
```

where the two attributes mark an interval. Now I want to get all the intervals that intersect e.g. `{3, 5}` (for now lets call those two numbers lower (`l`)- and upper(`u`)-bound). This should result in `{{3}, {4, 5}}`.

I already thought about an approach building a huge SQL-query that checks for every row to be returned for the following four cases:

```
a >= l && b <= u   // attribute-given interval completely enclosed by bounds
a <= l && b <= u   // attribute-given interval falls out to "the left"
a >= l && b >= u   // attribute-given interval falls out to "the right"
a <= l && b >= u   // bounds are completely enclosed by attribute-given interval
```

However I wondered if there´s a smarter approach using any built-in-function two perform such an intersection.

I´m using Oracle 11g for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that your interval pairs are *ordered* (i.e. `a <= b` for all rows) you could use this formula to check if intervals intersect:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyIntervals
WHERE LEAST(b, u) >= GREATEST(a, l)
```

The idea is to see if the smaller of the right sides of the two intervals is greater than the greatest of the left sides.

The formula above will return all rows where intervals overlap *or* touch. If you do not want touching intervals, use `>` in place of `>=`.

Comment: Wow, that was rediculous fast... have to validate it though, but for my first test it seems quite good. How can I manage it that luwer- and upperbounds are fix, so that the resulting intervals are cutted at those bounds? See my example of `{{3}, {4, 5}}` for what I mean.

Comment: @HimBromBeere When intervals intersect, the intersection can be found as a pair `(GREATEST(a, l), LEAST(b, u))`. For your example of `(3, 5)` and the matching row `(4, 6)`, `GREATEST` would return `4`, and `LEAST` would return `5`, giving your `(4, 5)` as the result. For the touching interval `(2, 3)` both `LEAST` and `GREATEST` would return `3`.

Comment: I ment that `{3, 5}` will also match the `3` from very first interval (`{2, 3}`).

Comment: @HimBromBeere The same formula would give you a `(3, 3)` pair.

Comment: Ahh, I see. But shouldn´t we introduce anything to the selection-part itself to just CUT the intervals. Currently we only select the intersecting intervals without actuall PERFORMING that intersection. However I could also do this afterwards when iterating the result-set.

Comment: This solution will prevent any indexes on A and or B from being used. It would be better to use the functionally equivalent `A<=U and L<=B` which does not prevent the usage of indexes.

Comment: @Sentinel You don't have any faith in Oracle's query optimizer, do you? I mean, you think it wouldn't see through the `LEAST` and `GREATEST` calculation to see through the expression and use indexes when it can?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
select *
  from MyIntervals MI
 where MI.A <= U
   and L <= MI.B
```

This will get all the possibilities where your interval overlaps the leading edge, or the trailing edge of your target interval, or your interval completely contains, or is completely contained by your target interval.

This works when A <= B and L <= U since when the two ranges overlap in any way, the start of each range will always be less than the end of the other range.  If they don't overlap, then there are only two situations where they won't, one is where A > U and the other is where B < L which can be rewritten as L > B.  That is the don't overlap when (A > U) | (L > B), and they do over lap when NOT((A > U) | (L > B)). Applying [De Morgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws):

```
 NOT((A > U) | (L > B)) 
 = NOT(A > U) & NOT(L > B)
 = (A <= U) & ( L <= B)
```

Comment: This will only select those intervals from table that completely contain the given one. What I need are also those that are completely or partly contained within the given one.

Comment: Take a closer look at the predicate.  It will get all four permutations of overlap, assuming that A is always <= B, and that L is always <= U